# Kaspersky TS blocking apt-get upgrade and marking files as HEUR:Trojan.Script.Generic

Tags: kali-linux, antimalware

I have just recently downloaded kali linux onto my VM software and i was doing apt-get upgrade in terminal and some files got blocked by my kts and i was wondering whether it was a false positive as what its trying to download is tools for code injections, do i allow the files to download or should i listen to kaspersky?
the 2 links -
http://ftp.hands.com/kali/pool/main/c/commix/commix_3.0-20191111-0kail1_all.deb//data.tar.xz//data.tar//./usr/share/commix/src/core/shells/bind_tcp.py
and
http://ftp.hands.com/kali/pool/main/l/laudanum/laudanum_1.0%2br36-0kail4_all.deb//data.tar.xz//data.tar//./usr/share/laundanum/jsp/cmd.war//cmd.jsp

Comment: I got the same symptoms. So we disabled Kaspersky protection until `apt-get update` and` apt-get upgrade`

Comment: *"...t was a false positive as what its trying to download is tools for code injections..."* - doesn't that mean that you were trying to download files which are designed to be used when hacking systems? It is not unlikely that Kaspersky marked these as malicious because exactly of this, i.e. not a false positive but you still want to get the files exactly for this hacking purpose.

Comment: Anti-Virus on a pentesting system is not a good idea, as AV software is designed to protect end-users and you're clearly not one. It's as if you hired a guard looking for weapons, inside a weapons factory, and he'd freak out every 12 seconds.